# Can I reduce the width and height of my Image Sprite?

Tags: css, css-sprites

I have a button and I am displaying an image as a background to that button using image sprites. But how can I adjust the height and width of the background image, so I can center the image and display it smaller or bigger.

My HTML Button is:

```
<input type="button" style="background-image:url(http://s14.postimg.org/cvj2v79gx/csg_539205e53e474.png)" class="sprite-Answer1 callIcons" />
```

I created a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DsXs7/).

Comment: you have to use background-size and eventually update background-position. http://jsfiddle.net/DsXs7/18/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the image, resize it with a photo-edit program, and upload to your server + relative URL.

Answer (score 1):

In newer browsers you can try using `background-size`:

```
background-size : 50% 50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it easiest to use background-size: cover.

http://jsfiddle.net/DsXs7/19/

In the fiddle, you can see the width of the background sprite is half.  You'd need to adjust background position so it shows the sprite image you want.  For ie8 and below, you might want to add a conditional stylesheet and a non-spite image.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles-ie.css" /><![endif]-->
```

In the IE styles, just use a resized icon.  Don't feel bad about it, because I don't think anyone uses IE on mobile devices, so the speed hit shouldn't be too offensive.